# Validating that 2 fields are equal in my form?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to validate that two fields are equals inside my form. For example, I have two fields called password and confirm password. My validator should make my form invalid if they are not equal.

Here's the validator I created:

```
export function matchFields(firstControl: string, secondControl: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    
    const firstValue = control.get(firstControl)?.value;
    const secondValue = control.get(secondControl)?.value;

    if(!firstValue) {
        console.error(`Cannot find control named: ${firstControl}. Please make sure it exists in your form.`);
        return null;
    }
    
    if(!secondValue) {
        console.error(`Cannot find control named: ${secondControl}. Please make sure it exists in your form.`);
        return null;
    }
    
    const result = (firstValue === secondValue);
    return result ? null : { matches: false };
  };
}
```

And here's how I use it in my component:

```
public setPasswordForm = new FormGroup({
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
});

constructor() {
    this.setPasswordForm.setValidators(matchFields('password', 'confirmPassword'));
}
```

My problem is, these lines always return null. Why is that? I'm using angular version 15.

```
const firstValue = control.get(firstControl)?.value; //always returns null? why?
const secondValue = control.get(secondControl)?.value; //always returns null? why?
```

I tried to console.log the FormGroup and those two fields seem to be existing.

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKqon.png)

Comment: This is probably because you’re already running the function at the time you’re setting up the validator. Your match function Should return an inner function (which is the actual ValidatorFn). Outer function registers the controls, inner function does the actual validations.

Comment: If that's the case, then how do i pass the name of the fields that I want to validate? could you please give an example?

Comment: On my phone right now so a bit hard. So as I said, your outer function registers the controls. It needs to return an inner function that does the actual checking. A closure basically..

Comment: Wait.. I might be talking BS here.. it seems you’re already doing that. Does the inner function actually trigger when you type into the form?

Comment: Yes, the validator gets called every time i type into the form.

Comment: ok I just realized it's actually really null because I have not typed anything yet. the error goes away after i type something.... lol. I should check if its dirty or something. I should prolly go to sleep. sorry :/

Comment: Hmm.. sorry for my earlier confusion. This actually looks correct. The only thing I have doubts about really is the way you register it. Looks okay, but never done it like that. Can you try adding the validation as the second value in FormGroup (in array I think?)

Comment: Whaha! Okay so I’t actually working . Nice!